# "Cleartext" password with bindpw in nslcd.conf?

Tags: ldap, bind, password-encryption, sasl

I want to know if there is a way to not put the password in clear nslcd.conf file? A hash or so I've heard of a method with SASL but I do not know how it works.

Thank you in advance